# No GPS after Kali and Kismet update 2019.07.R2

Tags: linux, kali-linux, gps

I'm unable to get GPS connection via kismets new webserver UI after a Kali update which also updated kismet to 2019.07.R2-kali4.

Gear: latop,GPS BU-353S4 W/SiRF Star IV chipset,WIFI AWUS036NHA, 2019.07.R2-kali4

So, before the update, this system worked great every time but now I'm able to get the GPS signal through a terminal using "gpsd -n -N -D 2 /dev/ttyUSB0 and then cgps -s ". I start Kismet it using "kismet -c wlan1mon" and then using a web browser go to localhost:2502 and things seem to go well but then I noticed there's no GPS signal. Kismet says "gpd connection lost" when I click the gps icon in the upper RT corner of the UI window.

Can I please get some help with this issue. Also, my skill level is just slightly above a beginner. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just install gpsd and gpsd-clients
after you start the cgpsd0 to see if it work
close it and then run kismet ,and gps should work just

find